# Why do I see my OS X account picture in GMail on my Android phone?

Tags: gmail, login

I found a very confusing thing today: When I look at messages in the GMail app on my Android phone, the picture I set for the login on my Macbook at work is my icon in the message thread. I never did anything to integrate GMail with my OS, never requested that the image be shared anywhere, and can't find a way to delete it.

This leads to two questions:

1) How do I ensure that my laptop login picture is not associated with anything, anywhere, ever?

2) Where would I go to submit feedback to Apple in order to tell them "never, ever do things like this"?

Comment: Do you use your gmail account for messaging (Jabber/XMPP) using iMessage (or iChat in older OS versions)? Did you create the gmail e-mail account on the Mac?

Comment: I have logged in through Adium, but not iMessage. Is there a chance Adium did it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) As you clarified in the comments, you have used your GMail account for instant messaging using Adium. My guess would be that Adium took your OS X account picture (or you assigned it manually) and synchronized it with Google. It should be easy to verify this by changing your contact picture in Adium.

I can`t test it right now, but will try later and also try to come up with a solution to turn of the synchronization.

2) https://ssl.apple.com/support/feedback/

But I don't think that OS X has anything to do with it, since I believe that the updating of your GMail avatar was done by Adium.